# How To Supress MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException Duplicate Entry

Tags: c#, mysql, error-handling

So I have a database with a unique constraint of multiple columns. Obviously to prevent duplicates. When debugging my application, my console is absolutely filled with `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException`s

Is there a way to supress these as this is the intended function of the database? Catching the exception doesn't seem to do it. It will handle it based on my `catch(MySqlException e)` statement, but still shows the `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException` in the console.

Here is my code:

```
public void InsertNewTeamHistory(TeamHistoryRow teamHistoryRow)
    {
        //open connection
        if (this.OpenConnection)
        {
            try
            {
                var query =
                    "INSERT INTO teamhistory(MatchURL, Date, TeamOne, TeamOneScore, TeamTwo, TeamTwoScore, Map, Event, Outcome) " +
                    "VALUES(?MatchURL, ?Date, ?TeamOne, ?TeamOneScore, ?TeamTwo, ?TeamTwoScore, ?Map, ?Event, ?Outcome)";

                //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
                using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, _connection))
                {
                    if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("?MatchURL", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = teamHistoryRow.MatchUrl;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("?Date", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = teamHistoryRow.Date;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("?TeamOne", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = teamHistoryRow.TeamOne;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("?TeamOneScore", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = teamHistoryRow.TeamOneScore;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("?TeamTwo", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = teamHistoryRow.TeamTwo;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("?TeamTwoScore", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = teamHistoryRow.TeamTwoScore;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("?Map", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = teamHistoryRow.Map;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("?Event", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = teamHistoryRow.Event;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("?Outcome", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = teamHistoryRow.Outcome;

                        //Execute command
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        //close connection
                        this.CloseConnection();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Failed - Connection to the DB NOT open.");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException e)
            {
                switch (e.Number)
                {
                    case 1062:
                        Console.WriteLine("Found Duplicate TeamHistoryRow, Not Inserting.");
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        Console.WriteLine("Well, we fucked up.");
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    this.CloseConnection();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to do if the record already exists? Do you want to update that record with the values or simply ignore the insert and continue?

Comment: Ignore the insert and continue. But I don't want it to output the `Exception thrown: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in MySql.Data.dll` as I'm processing thousands or rows a minute and it makes it very hard to read my actual program output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySql has a nice and easy to use feature that adds to your statement a rule on what to do when a duplicate key is found.

```
INSERT INTO ..... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE .....
```

So your query statement could be rewritten as

```
INSERT INTO teamhistory(MatchURL, Date, TeamOne, TeamOneScore, TeamTwo, 
                       TeamTwoScore, Map, Event, Outcome) 
                       VALUES(?MatchURL, ?Date, ?TeamOne, 
                       ?TeamOneScore, ?TeamTwo, ?TeamTwoScore, 
                       ?Map, ?Event, ?Outcome) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE MatchUrl = ?MatchUrl
```

This assumes that the field MatchUrl is your key that triggers the duplicate exception. So when the duplicate key is detected the sql executes the UPDATE changing nothing in your table

The same logic is available in other database system through the standardized [command MERGE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL))

Comment: Fantastic, sir! Thank you VERY MUCH. This causes the MySql `cmd` to complete successfully, and not error out. BEAUTIFUL! I have selected your answer as the best answer!